# Get calendar tasks for several employees using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I need to store appointment data from several exchange calendars. Right now I have a solution that loops through a Group containing employees using:

```
ExpandGroupResults myGroupMembers = service.ExpandGroup("AllUsers@....onmicrosoft.com");
foreach (EmailAddress address in myGroupMembers.Members){
   service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, address.Address);
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.
    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
   CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
    CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
                cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);
                FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

                foreach (Appointment a in appointments) {
                        file.Write(address.Address + ";");
                        file.Write(a.Subject.ToString() + ";");
                        file.Write(a.Start.ToString() + ";");
                        file.Write(a.End.ToString() + ";");
                        file.WriteLine();
                }

}
```

Using `service.ImpersonatedUserId` for each employee is really slow, have someone done anything similar?

**UPDATE**
I will fetch data from around 100 employees from myGroupMembers. If this is the way to go I will go with it since I can't find another solution.

Comment: What you have so far is correct. What are you doing for //export stuff from calendar? Are all these users on the same server?

Comment: @MichaelMainer-Microsoft Yes, they are on the same server. I will update question with additional export stuff-code.

Answer (score 1):

One option to optimize is to remove the unnecessary CalendarFolder.Bind line. That will reduce one call per address. Also, it is returning the full folder property set which you aren't using so that is throw away data sent over the wire.

Then replace the calendar.FindAppointments line with ExchangeService.FindItems method. Have the FindItems call target the calendar folder, and give it the CalendarView.

That should reduce the number of calls by 50%.